# Entropy calculation for MNIST dataset to form classification decision tree

Tags: r, decision-trees

I am trying to get classification tree in R. I am using MNIST (handwritten digit dataset) to train my decision tree. The dataset has 28*28 pixel box. Pixels are organized in row-wise. Pixel values are 0 to 255. 0 means background (white), 255 means foreground (black). I have to calculate entropy to get best attributes among 784 attributes (pixel0 to pixel783). Can anyone suggest, how to calculate entropy or information gain for these dense attributes?

Comment: Info gain from what to what? are you looking for feature's predictiveness?

Comment: I am applying ID3 algorithm (Classification tree). So, right from root node, i have to calculate entropy and IG. IG for feature predictiveness. [I have referred this link for ID3 implementation ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wL9aogTuZw8)

Comment: That means you want the entropy of a split in the node, not of the image.